# Tableau 'map' type messing up sized visualization

Tags: tableau-api

I am making a map chart in Tableau where I have lat and long coordinates and I want the dots showing these locations to be bigger or smaller based on the number of mosquitos caught in the specific traps (marked by the lat and lon coordinates). This works perfectly as long as I use the 'automatic' chart type:
[image]
However if I switch to the 'map' type, the dots do not represent the sizes anymore. Notice that I did not change ANYTHING else but the chart type:
[image]
Could someone explain why this happens and how to 'fix' it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Tableau to display marks as circles, choose the circle mark type. No need to choose the map mark type unless you are trying to fill regions, say counties. In that case, you would usually put your measure on color instead of size.